How to fill custom rotated 2D box?
I have a 2D box. It has a pivot point (its center), position, rotation and 4 rotated points. Each point has position, rotation and pivot.
2D box now has: no fill and cross fill.
I want to add full box (square) fill.
I'm on Arduino Uno now.
I'll switch to ESP-WROOM-32 soon.
Vector2 is my homemade "array".
//128x64 OLED using

enum FillType {
  FILLTYPE_NONE,
  FILLTYPE_CROSS,
  FILLTYPE_FAST_FILL,
  FILLTYPE_FILL
};

class Vector2 {
  public:
  Vector2(int nx, int ny) {x = nx; y = ny;}
  Vector2 Addx(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
  {
    return Vector2(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
  }
  int x;
  int y;
};

class Empty_2D {
  public:
  /*
    Deleted functions:
    position() >> returns Vector2
    rotation() >> returns float
    SetPosition(Vector2)
    SetRotation(float)
    SetPivot(Vector2)
  */
  private:
  int posX;
  int posY;
  int pivotX;
  int pivotY;
  float local_angle;
};

class Box_2D {
  public:
  /*
    Deleted functions:
    SetPivot(Vector2) [set center]
    SetPosition(Vector2)
    SetRotation(float)
  */
  void Draw(FillType fill)
  {
    oled.line(point1.position().x, point1.position().y, point2.position().x, point2.position().y);
    oled.line(point2.position().x, point2.position().y, point3.position().x, point3.position().y);
    oled.line(point3.position().x, point3.position().y, point4.position().x, point4.position().y);
    oled.line(point4.position().x, point4.position().y, point1.position().x, point1.position().y);
    if(fill == FILLTYPE_CROSS)
    {
      oled.line(point1.position().x, point1.position().y, point3.position().x, point3.position().y);
      oled.line(point2.position().x, point2.position().y, point4.position().x, point4.position().y);
    }
    if(fill == FILLTYPE_FILL)
    {
      //idk
    }
  }
  private:
  int pivot_x;
  int pivot_y;
  Empty_2D point1;
  Empty_2D point2;
  Empty_2D point3;
  Empty_2D point4;
};

I try to fill using 2x rect.

You will need to calculate scanlines, or just use a graphics library

What library are you using, or did you roll your own interface?
